# Monitor Synchronization

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to build a layered testbench for memory verification. I am displaying read_data(out data of the memory) at driver and monitor side. The problem is monitor is only getting triggered at the start of the cycle. But I want a monitor to be triggered whenever read_write =0. Why is a monitor not considering all the scenario? 
In environment class, I am calling run method of driver, monitor and generator.
Link: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/389q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems with your code. First is you probably want a `forever` loop in your monitor class. The way it is written now in the run() method is that it waits for 2 clock cycles, then waits for `read_write == 0`, and then it is finished.

Another problem is you are using the modport name `monitor` in your hierarchical references. A modport is not a scope, it is an access list used when declaring a virtual interface variable.

And finally, when working with `clocking` blocks, you should only use the clocking bock event for synchronization, never the *raw* signals.

```
class monitor;

  virtual intf.monitor vintf;

  function new(virtual intf.monitor vintf);
    this.vintf=vintf;
  endfunction

  task run();
    forever
      @(vintf.mo) // No ; here. You would get stuck in an infinite loop
      begin
        $display("--------MONITOR STARTS--------");
        @(vintf.mo iff (vintf.mo.read_write==0))
      begin
      $display("--------MONITOR READDATA--------");
        $display(vintf.mo.read_data);
        $display(vintf.mo.address);
      end
      end  
  endtask 
endclass
```